# Correct way to create objects when needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I am learning Ninject as my first DI container, I guess all containers will have similar idea, so here is my question.

I have a class UserRepository that has a function:

```
//constructor
public UserRepository(Kernel kernel) { _kernel = kernel; } 

public UserDataModel CreateNewUser(string title, string firstname,
    string lastname, int age ...) 
{
    //I have the kernel registered everything properly
    //Getting a new user object from the kernel
    var user = _kernel.Get<UserDataModel>(); 

    user.Title = title;
    user.Firstname = firstname;
    user.Lastname = lastname;
    ...
    return user;
}
```

Is it the correct way to use the kernel? I read from other posts that exposing and passing around the kernel is a bad bad idea. If so, what is the correct way to do it?

**EDIT**

some of my code demostrating the use of a tempUser object

```
public int UpdateSaUser(Guid msuserid, UserProfile saprofile,
    string accesstoken = "") 
{
    using (var db = new SaModelContainer()) 
    {
        var row1 = MakeNewRow(msuserid, saprofile, accesstoken);
        var row2 = db.SaUser.SingleOrDefault(
            r => r.MsUserId.Equals(msuserid));
        if (row2 == null) { //add new
            db.sauth_User.Add(row1);
        } else { //modify
            var entry = db.Entry(row2);
            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(row2); 
            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(row1); 
        }
        return db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private SaUser MakeNewRow(Guid msuserid, UserProfile saprofile,
    string accesstoken = "") 
{
        var row = new SaUser {
            MsUserId = msuserid,
            Provider = (int)saprofile.Provider,
            ProfileId = saprofile.ID,
            Email = saprofile.Email,
            AccessToken = accesstoken,
            FirstName = saprofile.FirstName,
            LastName = saprofile.LastName,
            FullName = saprofile.FullName,
            UserName = saprofile.Username,
            DisplayName = saprofile.DisplayName,
            Country = saprofile.Country,
            DoB = StringParser.ParseDate(saprofile.DateOfBirth),
            Gender = (int)saprofile.GenderType,
            Language = saprofile.Language,
            ProfileURL = saprofile.ProfileURL,
            ProfilePictureURL = saprofile.ProfilePictureURL
        };

        return row;
}
```

Comment: Don't inject the `Kernel` into the constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389960/dependency-injection-container-in-constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject your dependencies also know as dependency Injection. Instead of injecting the kernel.

Example (this is know as constructor injection):

```
private UserDataModel _userDataModel;

[Inject]
public UserRepository(UserDataModel userDataModel)
{
    _userDataModel = userDataModel;
}

//Any other method can now use _userDataModel
```

You should probably make an interface of your `UserDataModel` so you can mock or stub it in your unit tests. And bind that interface to the correct implementation using ninject see the example. Then there is no need for the attributes.

[Ninject MVC Documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application)

[Good mvc example](http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html)

A list of UserDataModels is not a dependency. I.E. You have some kind of database or other dependecy (WCF Service, Web Service, Entity Framework, nHibernate, ...) where the users are coming from that is your dependency.

```
public UserRepository(EntityFrameworkContext context)
{
    //The entity framework context is the dependency that you don't want to test.
    _context = context;
}

public List GetAllUsers()
{
   return _context.Users.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Predefined a model and inject it is by the book, but it doesnt seem to solve my headache. In runtime, how does that work if I need things dynamically. Say, I want a List<UserDataModel> don't know how many until runtime requested. I can't just go public UserRepository(List<UserDataModel>); all at the beginning? Or some functions don't need it, we it inject anyway? Isn't it more flexible to ask kernel when needed? The 2 links & sample codes I have read and downloaded last few days. I can't see a direct example related to this one.

Comment: The kernel shouldn't be passed around. How can u set up our unit tests when u don't know what the kernel will try to require ? Mocking a kernel is also a stupid idea. If you pass all the dependencies to the class, you can perfectly test every scenario in your test. If your class is getting to messy try separating the concerns more.

Comment: @ PrebenH. I know it sounds like a bad idea. That's why I asked. If some function generates a List<UserDataModel>, or requires one, that is a very common case, isn't it? It is not messy. But it is all by user dynamic request at runtime. Until then I can't pre-make an unknown list to inject. Could you give me a correct example how they are normally done please?

Comment: If you just want to create a UserDataModel you can do new UserDataModel(). Because the user data model isn't a dependency. If you want a better solution include more sample code on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ PrebenH, +1. Nicely explained. My headache is fading away :D ... okay, further to your reply, if I was to make a tempUser for example, totaly private use within 2 private functions, I can just new them, and it is not a bad idea? I don't have to asked the DIC to make me one?

Comment: The dependent object describes what software component it depends on to do its work. The injector decides what concrete classes satisfy the requirements of the dependent object, and provides them to the dependent. See wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection A tempUser is not a dependency

Comment: @ PrebenH, Some more code included to show how I used a tempUser

Comment: @ PrebenH, thank you very much. I am a newbie to it, so I read the example and monkey see monkey do, but I really didnt know why and most articles assume I know already. With your help it has cleared my head alot!